# OpenCV - Debug DLL libraries missing

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, dll, opencv3.0

I am trying to compile a simple openCV program through Visual Studio 2013. Following this tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html, I have setup all the opencv libraries. The program builds no problem, but when I run it in debug mode I get an error that reads:

`The program can't start because opencv_highgui310d.dll is missing.`

This occurs with `videoio`, `imgproc` and `core`. All of which are found in the added directory in the property sheet.

I have added the directories to the linker from the install folder in my opencv_build dir.

Comment: DLL's are not used in the build process, so changing build settings does nothing.  It is the Windows OS that needs to find these DLL's when your program runs.  Thus the methods that Windows uses to find DLL's is done (search executable directory, search `PATH`, etc.)  [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the full rundown of how Windows searches and find DLL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows needs to find missing dlls. They are usually placed somewhere in your opencv folder, it should be easy to find them. After that, you can do either:

- Copy dlls directly to same folder with exe you are running (you will need to keep these in case of deployment as well)
- In visual studio change environment from: **Project** -> **'project name' properties** -> **Configuration properties** -> **Debugging** -> **Environment** and enter: `PATH = $path_to_opencv_dll_folder`